# Class constructor creates new class fields with variable names?

Tags: php, oop, properties

I'm trying to initialize a class through a constructor with PHP 5.5.13 but am getting some weird results. The setup is like this:

```
class foo{
     public $bar;
     public $top;
     public $bot = array();

     function __construct($bar, $top){
        $this->$bar = $bar;
        $this->$top = $top;
     }
}

$phonebook = array();
$user_input = $_POST['query'];
if(/* regex match */){
   foreach($valid_input[0] as $arr){
      $name_and_number = explode(" ", $arr);
      $phonebook[] = new foo($name_and_number[0], (int) $name_and_number[1]); //e.g. Bob, 123
      var_dump($phonebook[count($phonebook)-1]);
   }
}
```

The weird part is now, however that phonebook's var_dump returns:

```
object(foo)#1 (5) { ["bar"]=> NULL ["top"]=> NULL ["bot"]=> array(0) { } 
["Bob"]=> string(3) "Bob" ["123"]=> int(123) }
```

Running:

```
echo "$phonebook[0]->$bar";
echo "$phonebook[0]['Bob']"; //Since a Bob field apparently exists?
echo "$phonebook[0]->$Bob";  //Just to test if maybe a $Bob variable has been declared?
```

All return an empty page. I'm at a loss here. Is my constructor setup weird? Or the way I try to access the variables?

Comment: Remove the dollar sign: `$this->$bar` (The second..) With the data `Bob, 123` Your two code lines: `$this->$bar = $bar;
        $this->$top = $top;` will end up as: `$this->Bob = "Bob"; $this->123 = 123;`

Comment: Good lord... I knew it was going to be something silly. Thank you. If you want to add your comment as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is get rid of the second `$` sign like so

```php
class foo{
     public $bar;
     public $top;
     public $bot = array();

     function __construct($bar, $top){
        $this->bar = $bar;
        $this->top = $top;
     }
}
```

The reason why you're seeing the 'weird' results is because the value of `$bar` and `$top` are evaluated dynamically and will be used to create a new named property. Resulting, in your case, to a property named 'Bob' and '123'

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in these lines:

```
 function __construct($bar, $top){
    $this->$bar = $bar;
    $this->$top = $top;
 }
```

`$this->$bar` refers to the property that is named after the *value of* bar. So if you pass the name `Bob`, you actually set the property `Bob` to `'Bob'`.

Your intention, of course, is to set the property `bar`. To do that, remove the `$` sign. It must be omitted for properties:

```
$this->bar = $bar;
```

So it has nothing to do with the constructor, it's just the way you use properties anywhere. In a constructor or even out of class methods. `echo "$phonebook[0]->$bar"` should also be `echo "$phonebook[0]->bar";`.

Personally I think this is a weird and counter intuitive syntax, but I've once been in a serious fight over it with a PHP afficionado, so I don't dare to bring it up again. Just live with it. ;)